# How to remove particular cell from HTML table?

Tags: css, html, html-table, cell

Suppose I have HTML table and I want to remove one cell from HTML table something like this:

[image]

I have changed cell border color to white since the border color of whole table is black so it is showing grey color. Problem is I can't remove table border so I have used **border-collapse:collapse**

So how can I change it in such a way that border color remains black and cell is not appeared in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the cell by setting the `visibility` to `hidden`.

http://jsfiddle.net/S5tnv/

**CSS**

```
td {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use something like this:

```
table tr:last-child td:first-child { display: none; }
```

Comment: hey but it is deleting only last td of table

Comment: @lata it's only hiding, not deleted

Comment: @user1479606: yes if cell is deleted then following cells will be shifted towards left by default

Comment: @lata  Try using visibility:hidden; instead of display:none; to 'make it invisible' while keeping the other cells to the right of it (rather than having them collapse to the first cell's location).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, just try putting the style attribute in the cell that you wish to have with no border with a border size property of zero pixels:

```
<td style="border:0px"></td>
```