# How to delete a cell from a table in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to delete or at least make a cell disappear in a table in HTML.

I tried to put a class on the cell i want to disappear, then, with CSS, i tried to put a "visibility: hidden;" but it doesnt worck for this particular cell.

```
<td class="removecell"></td>

.removecell {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I expect the cell to disappear, though, nothing happend. No error message.

Here is a link to my Codepen : **[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Peyo5202/pen/RwbGaGm?editors=1000)**

Comment: it works fine..

Comment: are you trying to hide the entire cell or just the content inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  `display:none` to your `td`

```
.removecell{
display:none
}
```

and `visibility: hidden` also work maybe  something in your css is overriding it. try using `!important`

```
.removecell {
    visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

Comment: I think `display:none` is not good here. It adjusts other table cells and that is a big issue. `visibility:hidden` works fine..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
<td class="removecell"></td>

.removecell {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hello I find a similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804029/how-to-remove-particular-cell-from-html-table

Comment: `display:none` is not good in this case. It shifts other table cells towards left and that is a big issue. `visibility:hidden` works fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
<td id="removecell"></td>


<script>

    //this will shortened table width
    document.getElementById('removecell').style.display = "none"; 

    document.getElementById('removecell').style.visibility= "hidden";

    </script>
```

if you want to completly remove/delete the cell let me know but it will cost you to decrease width